# Is there a corresponding row 'header' method similar to this for column headers?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

To get column headers, this worked (ColHeaderValues = sheeResponses.getDataRange().getValues().shift();).

Is there a similar method to get the row headers?

Do I have to create and populate a two dimensional array to do this?

What I am trying to accomplish is being able to reference a specific row number by looking up the value in column one.

Thanks,
chuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
RowHeaderValues = sheetResponses.getDataRange().getValues().map(function(row){return row[0]});
```

Comment: While both piscator's response and Joel's response provided a solution; I went with Joel's as the answer because it seemed simply to my uneducated mind.  It also seems to have better captured the spirit of my question.  I upvoted both because they were good solutions.

Comment: "...it seemed simply to my... should be "... it seemed simpler to my..."

Answer (score 1):

You can use the find function of the 2D Arrays Library: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library

find(Object[][] data, intColumnIndex, String value): int

```
var data = sheetResponses.getDataRange().getValues();
ArrayLib.find(data, 0, "valueInColumnOne");
```

Comment: Nice, I will have to keep this library in mind for future projects.  Thank you for passing this along.